# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#ext-gen275"}

Tags: webdriverwait, getelementbyid, timeoutexception, findelement

getting unable to locate element exception

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(50)); 
driver.findElement(By.id("button-1205-btnIconEl")).click(); 
//      String title = driver.getTitle();
//      System.out.println("Title of the Browser :" +title);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen275")).click();
```

Above is my code - I am able to see the page upto the code `driver.findElement(By.id("button-1205-btnIconEl")).click();` after that its failing with the above exception.

below is the html source for that element, the Bold text one is the element I am looking

```
<dd class="box-folder"><div class="box-container" id="ext-gen259">

     ****
            
        <h2>Operational Reports</h2><p>Operational Reports</p></dd>
```

Comment: Is there an element with ID `ext-gen275` on the page?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel its like partial ID - its changing every time, below provided you the html code

<div id="document-item-icon" class="box-figure">
<div id="icon" class="folder"></div>
<span class="shadow" id="ext-gen343"></span>
<div class="hover">  </div>
</div>

Comment: that's not what I'm asking. The error says there's no element with that ID, you need to make sure it exists in the document

Comment: @MikeSzyndel No and I had given a new xpath element now 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value=\"Sign In\"]")).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(50));
  driver.findElement(By.id("button-1205-btnIconEl")).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(50));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='extdd-9']")).click();

getting the same error : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='extdd-9']"}

Comment: This element ID ("xpath","selector":"//span[@id='extdd-9']"})  is there and when I searched it pointed to the object.